# Cross-platform way of hiding cryptographic keys in C++?

Tags: c++, security, cross-platform, cryptography

My application needs to use a couple of **hard-coded symmetric cryptographic keys** (while I know that storing a public key would be the only perfect solution, this is non-negotiable). We want the keys to be stored **obfuscated**, so that they won't be recognizable by analyzing the executable, and be "live" in memory for as little time as possible - as to increase the difficulty of a memory dump retrieving them in clear-text. I'm interested in using **C++** features (using some sort of `scoped_key` comes to mind). The solution must be **portable** - Windows, Linux, MacOS -, so it cannot take advantage of the operating system crypto API.

How would you go about designing such a system? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't really possible to do. What problem are you trying to solve here?  Maybe there's another way to accomplish it.

Comment: it might be useful if you could explain why asymmetric crypto is not an option

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained what you want to achieve, rather than just to discuss how you want to achieve it. Since you claim that storing  public keys would be a perfect solution, this means that you either want to write software that can only encrypt (but not decrypt) or that you want to write software that needs to authenticate something. Without more details it is hard to make any useful comments.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Assymetric crypto is not an option because the system I'm building needs to be compatible with an older one that uses symmetric crypto. That is to say, both of them must generate the same output given the same input - it's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the general idea.

@Accipitridae, yes, it is only necessay to encrypt. The choice of symmetric crypto is not a good one, but I'm not in a position to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `scoped_key` can be simply a `KeyHolder` object on the stack. Its constructor takes the obfuscated buffer and makes a real key out of it and its destructor zeros out the memory and deallocates the memory.

As for how to actually obfuscate the key in the binary, One silly choice you might try is put inside a much larger random binary block and remember its offset and size and probably XOR it with some short random sequence.

If you do the XORing thing you can actually avoid ever having the real key in memory. simply modify the decryption to read a byte from the key and before using it, to XOR it with the appropriate value.

`*`Add here disclaimer on how foolish security through obscurity is`*`

Comment: Thanks for sparing the disclaimer - I am aware of that, but it _is_ better than no protection at all! The important thing is to keep in mind this is only a palliative, and any attacker who's both skilled and determined will work her way around it.

Answer (score 4):

All you're going for here is security through obscurity. If you have one of us come up with an idea, you won't even have that.

[John Skeet has a good article on this too.](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/obfuscation.html)

Do something random is all I can say.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered if this is actually the weak point in your program? Let's assume for the sake of argument that you're doing a license check - though other checks apply equally well. No matter how well hidden your key, and how well obfuscated your algorithm, at some point you have to do something like this:

```
if(!passesCheck()) {
  exit(1); 
}
```

Your potential adversary doesn't have to find the key, decrypt it, figure out the algorithm, or anything else. All they have to do is find the location in the code where you determine if the check succeeded, and replace the 'jnz' instruction with a 'jmp' to make the test pass unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. The problem I'm facing is not one of license checks, or any other check for that matter. It's a software that comes up with some data, encrypts it and sends it back to a server.

Comment: What's the goal here? If you're trying to prevent your users from reading the data, it's a moot point, since they can examine the data before it's encrypted. If you're trying to prevent them from modifying it, or prevent them from generating their own messages, you need to be aware that encryption on its own does _not_ guarantee integrity - you need either public key crypto or an HMAC for that.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Tamper Resistance software, such as [Cloakware](http://www.cloakware.com/) and [Arxan](http://www.arxan.com/).

TR is NOT cheap :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not take advantage of whatever platform you will run on, you cannot guarantee that you can effectively hide a symmetric cryptographic key in your program. You can assume that an attacker will have a debugger and will eventually figure out how to set a breakpoint in the function that has to use the key to decrypt. Then it's game over.

Answer (score -2):

Why not look at steganography, as you can hide the key in an image. It is possible to find the key, but if the image doesn't follow an obvious pattern (such as an image of space would) then it may be harder.  This can be cross-platform.